# как сгладить кривую, используя canvas bezier?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть точки, например: `[0, 0], [50, 50], [100, 0]`.

Как по ним найти контрольные точки для `bezierCurveTo`?

Я додумался только до того, что линия из контрольных точек должна быть параллельна линии из левой и правой точки.

Answer (score 0):

`power` - сила сглаживания (от 0 до 3);
`seg` - сегменты (координаты точек - `[[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]....]`), допустим, 
`[[0, 0], [100, 100], [200, 0], [300, 100], [400, 0], [500, 100]];`

Чтобы узнать аргументы для функций bezierCurveTo и quadraticCurveTo, пропустим их через эту функцию:

```
var smooth = function(power, seg) {
  var pow = (power) ? ((power > 0) ? 2 : -2) + power / 2 : 2.3;
  if (seg.length > 2)
    for (var i = 0; i < seg.length; i++) {
      var im = (i < 1) ? seg[seg.length - 2] : seg[i - 1];
      var ib = (i > seg.length - 2) ? seg[1] : seg[i + 1];
      var a = ((ib[0] + seg[i][0]) / 2 + (seg[i][0] + (seg[i][0] - ib[0]) * pow + ib[0]) / 2),
        b = ((ib[1] + seg[i][1]) / 2 + (seg[i][1] + (seg[i][1] - ib[1]) * pow + ib[1]) / 2),
        c = ((im[0] + seg[i][0]) / 2 + (seg[i][0] + (seg[i][0] - im[0]) * pow + im[0]) / 2),
        d = ((im[1] + seg[i][1]) / 2 + (seg[i][1] + (seg[i][1] - im[1]) * pow + im[1]) / 2);
      im[4] = ((seg[i][0] - c + seg[i][0]) + a + seg[i][0]) / 3 + 1;
      im[5] = ((seg[i][1] - d + seg[i][1]) + b + seg[i][1]) / 3 + 1;
      seg[i][2] = ((seg[i][0] - a + seg[i][0]) + c + seg[i][0]) / 3;
      seg[i][3] = ((seg[i][1] - b + seg[i][1]) + d + seg[i][1]) / 3;
    }
  return seg;
};
```

вот, что у нас получилось:

```
[[0,0,-75,25,51,101],[100,100,150,100,151,1],[200,0,250,0,251,101],[300,100,350,100,351,1],[400,0,450,0,576,76],[500,100,425,125]];
```

Здесь мы получили аргументы для bezierCurveTo и quadraticCurveTo.

Теперь мы можем нарисовать кривую на Canvas с помощью этого массива:

```
for (var i = 1; i < seg.length; i++) {
  if (seg[i - 1][5]) {
    ctx.bezierCurveTo((seg[i - 1][2]), (seg[i - 1][3]), (seg[i - 1][4]), seg[i - 1][5], (seg[i][0]), (seg[i][1]));
  } else if (seg[i - 1][3]) {
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo((seg[i - 1][2]), (seg[i - 1][3]), seg[i][0], (seg[i][1]));
  } else {
    ctx.lineTo((seg[i][0]), (seg[i][1]));
  }
}
```

[Пример на Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwedp4os/2/)